# python nested dict comprehension with tuple as key

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dict like so:

```
{ ('name', 'user1'): 'foo',
  ('user', 'user1'): 'bar',
  ('name', 'user2'): 'bat',
  ('user', 'user2'): 'baz' }
```

and I would like to convert to:

```
{ 'user1': {'name': 'foo', 'user': 'bar'}, 
  'user2': {'name': 'bat', 'user': 'baz'} }
```

I can do this with a default dict easily, but I would like to use dict comprehension.

So far I have:

```
{user: {key:value for (key, user), value in my_dict.items()}}
```

But user is not inside the loop, so I `name 'user' is not defined` error.

How can I achieve this with dict comprehension?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do nicely in a comprehension, even with nesting. The problem is that you want to aggregate results from multiple items, which requires a `zip` type effect.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you either get quadratic time complexity and excessive complexity, or you write it as a simple loop with a few conditions. Does it have to be a dict comprehension.

Comment: You could do this with a dict comprehension, but you'd have to pre-group the values, which would defy the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dict comprehension can be used if both key and value have a direct one-on-one relationship with the items in the sequence.

However, your output values are based on multiple entries in the input sequence. Unless you can *group* the items into a sequence per second value in the tuple key, you have to use a `defaultdict` setup.

Grouping is certainly possible with `itertools.groupby()` but that would require sorting, making that less performant compared to a `defaultdict` plus loop solution.

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

user = lambda item: item[0][1]

{user: {key[0]: value for key, value in grouped}
    for user, grouped in groupby(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=user), key=user)}
```

Output demo:

```
>>> {user: {key[0]: value for key, value in grouped}
...     for user, grouped in groupby(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=user), key=user)}
{'user2': {'name': 'bat', 'user': 'baz'}, 'user1': {'name': 'foo', 'user': 'bar'}}
```

This is a O(n log n) solution, versus the O(n) complexity of a `defaultdict` solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(dict)

for (key, user), value in my_dict.iteritems():
    output[user][key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working fine:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter 

d=dict({('name', 'user1'): 'foo', ('user', 'user1'): 'bar',
        ('name', 'user2'): 'bat',
        ('user', 'user2'): 'baz' })

l = []
for key, val in d.items() :
    l.append([key[1], key[0], val])

l.sort(key=itemgetter(0))

d_ = dict()
for key, group in groupby(l, lambda x: x[0]):
    dic = dict()
    for thing in group:
        dic[thing[1]] = thing[2]
    d_[key] = dic
```

note that groupby from itertools will work only if list was previously sorted.

Comment: why did you import print_function?

Comment: i am with python 3.0. print, if imported from future, is a method